# ActionController::UrlGenerationError missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am very new at ruby - trying out rails and I am stuck already trying to do a simple register form:

```
<%= form_for :user, url: user_path do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :email %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <%= f.label :password %><br>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

This is giving an error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"user"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Can anyone explain what this actually means?

EDIT:

I am following this tutorial, only changing posts to user: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: Do you have register form set up for `show` action?

Comment: I am extremely new to ruby and rails so this isnt making sense right now. Im following the official tutorial exactly but only changing posts to user

Answer (score 1):

form_for should always get an object.. like a user from the controller

```
# controller
def new
  @user = User.new
end

# form
<%= form_for @user,...
```

Or you can use the form_tag method, which is not relying on an object..

Comment: That gives another error: uninitialized constant UserController::User

Comment: Do you have User model?

Comment: No the tutorial does not do this yet.  Unless the rails tutorial is wrong: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a similar problem.

controller name should be plural (i.e users) and

the first line in new.html.rb should look like:

```
<%= form_for :user, url: users_path do |f| %>
```